# mouse cursor only works when aframe inspector is open?

Tags: aframe

When I add

```html
<a-scene
    cursor="rayOrigin: mouse;"
    raycaster="objects: .rayclick;"
>
```

and

```html
<a-entity id="clickabl1" class="rayclick" rayclick>
```

and

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('rayclick', {
    init: function () {
        this.el.addEventListener('click',  (evt) => {
            alert(`I was clicked at ${this.el.id}`);
        });
    }
});
```

I end up with a strange situation... seemingly, the code does nothing, no click functionality at all--**except, when I open the aframe inspector, suddenly it works perfectly**. Then, when I close the inspector, back to nothing working.

What could this possibly mean?

Comment: Seems to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/w97t12rp/. Do you have an example with the issue?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski Thank you so much, I've been looking for a raycaster that works with Aframe & Blippar and all examples fired the raycaster on hovering a selectable model as well. This works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up later discovering that the inspector uses a mouse cursor that has no `objects` filter, which can make it work whenever other cursors might fail. I've also found that there are some subtle, difficult to reproduce bugs with cursors at times in current A-Frame.

But that explains why the cursors likely worked in the inspector, but not otherwise.

There is also the question of how the ray from a mouse cursor is drawn--its origin is going to be different when the inspector is open, so analyze that closely. (This is where I start finding subtle errors, especially if you adjust it after creating it.)